# PHP Redirect - Won't Stay on Current Page

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

```
<?php

  $links = array();

  $links[] = ''; //i left this blank so it stays on the current page, problem causer? 
  $links[] = 'http://domain2.com';
  $links[] = 'http://domain3.com';
  $links[] = 'http://domain4.com';

  $link = $links[array_rand($links)];

  header("Location: {$link}");

?>
```

What I want it to do is either redirect to domain 2, 3, 4 OR stay on the same page its on currently. I want it to be completely random, like the above script.

The above code works on Chrome, however, on FireFox and Internet Explorer it says it is

> server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete

Is there any way to make it work on ALL browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$links = array();

$links[] = ''; 
$links[] = 'http://domain2.com';
$links[] = 'http://domain3.com';
$links[] = 'http://domain4.com';

$link   = $links[array_rand($links)];

if ($link !== '') { // Don't pass an empty Location
    header("Location: $link"); // Remove the {}
}

?>
```

Remove the `{}` and it should be alright. Also, I think it would be best to not pass an empty Location header.

Comment: wow i spent like an hour trying to figure it out and wow lol simplest fix ever. thanks!